# Is that bug or feature..?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

...if vim won't allow:

```
highlight normal ctermbg=#e0e0e0
```

but will have no problem at all when doing (e.g.):

```
URxvt.color10: #e0e0e0       <- Xresources
highlight normal ctermbg=10
```

?

Bonus question is: Can I add `color-scheme` tag to this vim related question, when its description is

```
A color scheme is a set of colors used by an IDE
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

urxvt supports 256 colors. If you gave a `#rrggbb` color in .Xresource (or deprecated .Xdefault), urvt will pick the nearest color in the palette to this r/g/b tuple.

Terminal Vim can support up to 256 color too. But doesn't support the `#rrggbb` color format, instead, it supports a `{color-nr}` (`:h color-nr` for detail). It is `[0,t_Co)`. That is `t_Co` was set to 256, then the available color-nr is `[0,256)`.

Therefore urxvt and vim are different applications, they support different color formats. You cannot say it is a bug of vim because it doesn't support some format from other application.

And personally I think it is not a feature either, it is just a setting/option/config.

Answer (score 0):

`ctermfg`, `ctermbg` only accept:

- color names like `red` or `darkblue`,
- numbers from `0` to `15` (so-called "ANSI" colors) and from `16` to `255` (so-called "xterm" colors).

See `:help cterm-colors`.

`guifg` and `guibg` only accept:

- color names like `red` or `darkblue`,
- RGB values in hexadecimal notation like `#e0e0e0`.

See `:help gui-colors`.